# How To Configure Application Context with Functional Style Bean Registration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to recast my SpringBoot application to functional bean registration form for faster application start up times as mentioned in the Spring documentation for Spring Cloud Functions. Below is the code referenced in the documentation:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FunctionalSpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

  public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
    return value -> value.toUpperCase();
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
    context.registerBean("demo", FunctionRegistration.class,
        () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(uppercase())
            .type(FunctionType.from(String.class).to(String.class)));
  }

}
```

Here is my code attempting to follow the above exaple. The main difference is that my function is a separate class that implements the Java 8 function interface.

```
import com.example.functions.RockPaperScissors;
import com.example.model.Game;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionRegistration;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionType;
import org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionalSpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;

@Slf4j
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class Application implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

  private RockPaperScissors rockPaperScissors;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FunctionalSpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    applicationContext.registerBean(
        "rpsFunction",
        FunctionRegistration.class,
        () ->
            new FunctionRegistration<>(this.rockPaperScissors)
                .type(FunctionType.from(Game.class).to(String.class)));
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setRpsFunction(RockPaperScissors rockPaperScissors) {
    this.rockPaperScissors = rockPaperScissors;
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'target' must not be null. I know this is due to no application context being found but not sure why `FunctionalSpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);` isn't creating that context.